# TDD for Android and mobile

Tags: android, architecture, tdd, agile

I'm exploring driving the implementation of TDD on Android and am finding it quite difficult to justify.   While I'm a firm believer in TDD, and have used it in other design, I'm facing several key issues:

- The emulators are slow and unreliable.  It feels necessary to test on device to get good information.
- Testing on-device is typically too slow to be done with alternation between writing a basic snippet of code an a single test case.

I'm experimenting with an alternative approach of writing a full unit-test suite, writing a unit of code, and (if necessary) editing the test-suite to get full coverage of the unit.

The main question I have is:  What approaches/modifications to TDD are you using in the mobile space, and are you finding they work effectively?

Feel free to include any recommended frameworks, although this isn't the primary impetus of the question as there are good answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [RoboElectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) project.  It enables you to run tests outside of the emulator, so its meant to make Android TDD practical.

I will also try to separate out non-Android dependent code into a library/project that can be tested independently.

Comment: Follow up: How reliable do you find RoboElectric to be?  Part of the reason we moved off the emulator was speed, which RoboElectric solves, but part of it was that the emulator was often giving the wrong behaviour.  The described approach of returning null in all the android methods would give us pretty poor coverage since large portions of the framework are for native android behaviour.  Agree 100% on the non-Android dependent code, although I've found it to be a rarity so far, we've moved away from Java as part of our web stack.

Comment: Thats a really good question, you might want to start it as a separate on SO.  I haven't used RoboElectric extensively enough to give you a good answer, but I was very happy with it compared to the standard Android testing approach.  You might also find their Google Group to be useful: http://groups.google.com/group/robolectric?pli=1.  As a far as the non-Android dependent code, I was referring to code that is used within your Android app versus other parts of your system (just wanted to clarify).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the complete [RoboElectric Tutorial](http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2013/03/steps-to-configure-roboelectric-with.html) With source [Code](http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-unit-testing-with-robolectric.html)